# XSL joining 2 group statements for output

Tags: xslt, saxon

using saxon, i'm trying to print the totals from a table fetched by sql printed to a csv in a specific format.
the structure should be something like, and the totals i'm trying to get can be seen here too:

[image: table]

to keep in mind col2 can have any letter, but col4 can have only a, b or c

rough idea of how the input looks:

```
<ROW> 
  <ROW[1]> 
    <col1>1</col1>
    <col2>a</col2>
    <col3>1</col3>
    <col4>a</col4>
  </ROW[1]> 
  <ROW[2]> 
    <col1>2</col1>
    <col2>a</col2>
    <col3>2</col3>
    <col4>a</col4>
  </ROW[2]> 
  <ROW[3]> 
    <col1>3</col1>
    <col2>a</col2>
    <col3>3</col3>
    <col4>a</col4>
  </ROW[3]> 
  <ROW[4]> 
    <col1>6</col1>
    <col2>b</col2>
    <col3>2</col3>
    <col4>a</col4>
  </ROW[4]> 
  ... 
</ ROW>
```

doing totals just for col1 should be easy enough:

```
<xsl:template name = "totals">
  <xsl:for-each-group select = "//ROW" group-by="col2">
    <xsl:variable name="group_total">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/col1)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#013;&#010;'"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

but what would be the best way to join totals for col3 in the same row, like totals for a are next to a?
i thought calling a template and passing col2 value to run the totals by the same principle, but that has a problem when col2 doesn't have a value from col4

Comment: Consider to post a small but representative XML input sample. Are the `a` or `b` values in column 2 and 4 related by that value?

Comment: Sorry, but from this information I have really no idea what your input XML and output XML look like, or how they relate to each other. Presumably the first 7 rows of your table are input values and the last 3 rows are computed output values. I can't see how the computation of the totals for cols 3/4 needs to be any different from the computation for cols 1/2. I guess that's the danger of trying to infer a specification from a single example.

Comment: sorry about the confusion, i'm new to Saxon and working on a base that someone else has developed. 
yes, the first 7 should be input and last 3 are what i'm trying to get.
i'm not loading anything from xml at least directly, but each row in the table can be referenced by the column, so it should be something like:
<ROW>
  <ROW[1]>
    <col1></col1><col2></col2>...
  </ROW[1]>
...
</ ROW>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not good at imagining input structures but if you declare a key `<xsl:key name="by-col4" match="ROW" use="col4"/>` and then use `sum(key('by-col4', current-grouping-key())/col3)` inside of your `for-each-group` it might give the result you have shown.

Comment: that works great, just one more thing. i'd need it to run for values in col4 that are not in col2. 
is there a way to append them to the existing group or run afterwards without creating duplicates?

Comment: @meta, ask a new question with the necessary details.